# sqlplus printing the filename in error

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have created an sql script which calls many different sql files inside which may in turn call other sql scripts inside .Is it possible that when an error occurs in any of the sql file statements(grant,create,alter errors) ,it also prints the filename in which the error occurs showing the line ,error and the filename.

currently is prints the error and line (obviously)

```
dropping table temp_cl_link
DROP TABLE TEMP_CL_LINK CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I want it to show the file in which error occurs as well,if possible :

something like :

```
dropping table temp_cl_link
DROP TABLE TEMP_CL_LINK CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ERROR FILE : InstallLink.sql
```

Or in any other suitable format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
set APPINFO on
```

[read more here](http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2007/12/26/sqlplus-is-my-second-home-part-5-reading-the-name-of-currently-executing-script/)

Comment: using appinfo i can point to the current sql script.But using this how can i print the filename in the error as well?

Comment: @subodh1989, well, this is not exactly what you wanted, you'll still need to query `sys_context('USERENV', 'MODULE')`